# Remove unwanted standard fields in Dev Org?

Tags: administration, configuration, developer-org

I'd like to remove some less used standard fields in a dev org that are not present in my Enterprise org so that my metadata is a clean copy.  For instance, I'd like to remove `Contact.CleanStatus` and `Account.DandbCompanyId`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific on the features? A lot of them can be turned off via configuration... Not sure it is clear what you need

Comment: @SebastianKessel Fair.  Question revised.

Comment: are you attempting to move code from your Dev org to an enterprise sandbox?

Comment: @tjcinnamon Yes.  and an enterprise production org, as well.

Answer (score 0):

data.com is available in your developer organization and these fields are required for data.com clean feature.

You can not delete them, these fields are related with the feature even you don't use.